# How to create a HTML5 single line contentEditable tab which listens to Enter and Esc

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have a dashboard at work and I want people to be able to change the text on the tabs in order to create categories which fit them best.

I wanted single line text which would disregard changes on `Esc` or commit the changes on `Enter` or `Blur`.

I found the answer but figured I would post in order to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<span contenteditable="false"></span>
```

Here is the jQuery/javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[contenteditable]').dblclick(function() {
        $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        clearSelection();
        $(this).trigger('focus');
    });

    $('[contenteditable]').live('focus', function() {
        before = $(this).text();
        if($(this).attr('contenteditable') == "true") { $(this).css('border', '1px solid #ffd646'); }
    //}).live('blur paste', function() {
    }).live('blur', function() {
        $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #fafafa');
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""));

        if (before != $(this).text()) { $(this).trigger('change'); }
    }).live('keyup', function(event) {
        // ESC=27, Enter=13
        if (event.which == 27) {
            $(this).text(before);
            $(this).trigger('blur');
        } else if (event.which == 13) {
            $(this).trigger('blur');
        }
    });

    $('[contenteditable]').live('change', function() {
        var $thisText = $(this).text();
        //Do something with the new value.
    });
});

function clearSelection() {
    if ( document.selection ) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if ( window.getSelection ) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!!!

Comment: This is not enough, because I can still copy and paste into this textbox, which totally confuses your code and shows newlines anyway. Furthermore, your code strips all HTML (by using only 'text') - so I'm in fact not quite sure why you don't just use a textbox.

Comment: You can also use .html(). This is for text which is on a tab or something so you dont want it as a textbox. Only once they double-click, can you then edit it. As for 'paste', there is a commented line for that too. You can handle it as you please.

Comment: you should update this to `.on()` because `.live()` no longer exists.

Comment: .live() exists but is now depreciated. At the time of the post, .live() was the way to go. If you are using jQuery 1.7+, you should use .on().