# One line only for contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, paste

I try to make a element via using `contenteditable` to submit some title, That way I want users type/paste title only **one line**.

```
$('.title').on('keypress',function(e) {
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if(code == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
}).on('paste',function(){
   var text = $(this).text();
   $(this).html(text).focus();
});
```

Problem is `paste` event, When I paste some text, I can't use `.focus()` to **select/point** text to the **last charecter**.

What I did wrong ?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831482/contenteditable-single-line-input)

Comment: @Alex using CSS ! , Good idea thanks for link :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have idea now...

**jQuery :**

```
$('.title').on('keypress',function(e) {
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if(code == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
}).on('paste',function(){
   $('br,p',this).replaceWith(' ');
});
```

**CSS :** (not request)

```
.title br {display:none;}
```