# Truncate contenteditable with extra space

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `div` with **contentEditable** `true` attribute and I also apply `ellipsis` **CSS**.

The behavior of **contentEditable** it's fine when the content is less and not truncated.

[image]

But when you write extra content and content starts truncated it'll show extra whitespace on the right side.

[image]

[image]

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;  
  outline: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Browser? PC? Mac? Chrome PC it's perfect. Firefox PC it just continues no ellipsis at all.

Comment: Windows, Chrome version 73.0.3683.103.

Comment: Nevermind, there's like a space... but it's only a character maybe a character and a half of space...it's nothing like the screenshot in OP. Oh I see it doesn't hide the overflow, it just continues after  ellipse, correct?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, now you got the issue.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui does the `...` need to be visible while user is typing or only when the input is not focused?

Comment: @maqam7 the solution you trying to share with me, it's already available at the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a possible solution for this. you might need to change your HTML structure little. Take a parent element and wrap your truncated element into it and play with focus attribute.

Here is an example.

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

span {
  outline: 0;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span:not(:focus) {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span contenteditable="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one I was onto a similar solution with `:focus` but had not considered the lack of `:focus`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but there is a problem in your answer. You have to click 2 times outside then text truncated apply and ellipsis 3 dots appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 solutions :
First is multiline and second is in Single line.
Check out both snippet below :

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  height: 20px;
}

span {
  outline: 0;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span:not(:focus) {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div contentEditable="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

span {
  outline: 0;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span:not(:focus) {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div contentEditable="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I removed **text-overflow: ellipsis;*** as it was creating that white space issue
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831482/contenteditable-single-line-input)

```css
div[contenteditable="true"] {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

div[contenteditable="true"] br {
  display: none;
}

div[contenteditable="true"] * {
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the div back to the left on blur.

```js
function scrollBack(el) {
    el.scrollLeft = 0;
}
```

```css
div {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    outline: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-rendering: initial;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 350px;
}

div:focus {
    text-overflow: initial;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" onblur="scrollBack(this)"></div>
```